# How to get rid of "Press ENTER or type command to continue"

Tags: vimscript, ctags

I'm using `ctags` to code C++ with vim.

I set two shortcuts of `ctags` as below:

```
autocmd VimEnter * silent! !eval 'ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extras=+q --language-force=C++ -o newtags; mv newtags .tags' &
function! Jump(type)
    if filereadable(".tags")
        if a:type == "single"
            execute "normal! 2\<C-]>"
            execute "normal :NERDTreeFind\<CR>"
            execute "normal :wincmd p\<CR>"
        else
            execute "normal! g\<C-]>"
            "execute "normal :redraw!"
        endif
    else
        execute "normal :echo 'tags file not ready'\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <C-]> :call Jump('single')<CR>
nnoremap g<C-]> :call Jump('multi')<CR>
```

As the `autocmd` command may need some time to finish, I write a function `Jump`.

For now, everything works well except that I always get a `Press ENTER or type command to continue` after typing `g<C-]>`.

I've tried to add `execute "normal :redraw!"` but it doesn't seem to work...

Also, I cannot use `silent` too, because `g<C-]>` has some necessary output:
[image]

If I use `silent`, all the output above will disappear.

Comment: And you press the number on the output of `g<C]` and then get the "Press ENTER..." prompt?

Comment: @Ralf  No, I simply press `g<C]` and then get that. I cannot understand because `execute "normal :redraw!"` works on my Mac OS but doesn't work on my ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try the following. It directly uses `:tag` and `:tjump` instead of using the mappings. I also removed the unneeded `execute ...` stuff.

```
function! Jump(type)
    if filereadable(".tags")
        if a:type == "single"
            execute "tag " . expand("<cword>")
            NERDTreeFind
            wincmd p
        else
            execute "tjump " . expand("<cword>")
        endif
    else
        echo 'tags file not ready'
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Wonderful! It works.